# Why is the TPU not recognized on my Google Cloud TPU VM instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu

I have launched a Google Cloud TPU VM instance and installed the latest version of JAX, but it cannot see my TPU.  Following the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting/trouble-jax I encounter the following:

```
>>> import jax
>>> jax.devices()
WARNING:absl:No GPU/TPU found, falling back to CPU. (Set TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0 and rerun for more info.)
[CpuDevice(id=0)]
>>> TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0
>>> jax.devices()
[CpuDevice(id=0)]
```

All of the Google Search results I have seen for this error suggest installing JAX with CUDA support, but shouldn't that be unnecessary with TPUs?

Comment: Could you share what TPU VM version are you using and what commands you ran to reproduce this?

Comment: can you run `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0 python3` and then import jax, so that we can see better logs there?

Comment: Am having the same problem, am getting `TPU platform initialization failed: NOT_FOUND: No ba16c7433 device found.`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to upgrade the jax version.

```
pip3 install -u jax[tpu] -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/libtpu_releases.html
```

EDIT: Actually it seems like this is a bug, refer to:

https://github.com/google/jax/issues/13260